Hard instances of 3-colouring
I'm working on an algorithm to check if some arbitrary graph is 3-colourable (vertex colouring).
In the process of testing and debugging, I require instances of graphs that are 3-colourable.
I've used some of DIMACS format instances from here:
https://mat.tepper.cmu.edu/COLOR/instances.html
The issue is that these are all instances of k-colouring, and their algorithms return k, while mine returns true/false on whether a 3-colouring is present. I've gotten correct answers for all those I could run (can't run very large instances like the ones above 150 vertices on my laptop, looking into supercomputing resources right now).
Specifically, I got correct answers for the queen graphs, and the Mycielski transformation graphs, all answered false.
For true instances I used the following:

Petersen graph
The graph in the image in this wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch%27s_theorem

I'm looking for hard instances of 3-colouring; are there any such resources available? I'm having difficulty finding them online.

There are many ways to construct harder instances.
One simple and reliable approach is to use the reduction that proves 3-coloring is NP-complete, i.e., the reduction from 3SAT to 3-coloring.  Pick any hard 3SAT instance, then apply the reduction to transform it into a graph, and then testing 3-colorability of the graph is as hard as testing satisfiability of the 3SAT formula.
Another approach is to look in the research literature for papers on the subject.  See, e.g.,
Constructive generation of very hard 3-colorability instances.  Kazunori Mizuno, Seiichi Nishihara. Discrete Applied Mathematics, 156 (2008) pp.218-229.
You could also examine papers that cite that paper, and papers they cite.
